# Blank screen / 404 when trying to access some assets on AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, assets

I'm seeing a blank screen when accessing an asset on Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.3

When we try to access the asset like below, we are seeing a blank screen:
https://localhost:4502/content/dam/promo-tiles/indy500-v4-1135-1920x1920%20(1).jpg

[image]

Snippet from error log:

`25.05.2018 13:15:59.980 *ERROR* [192.150.10.208 [1527268559974] GET /content/dam/promo-tiles/indy500-v4-1135-1920x1920%20(1).jpg HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.acs.commons.util.ResourceDataUtil Error creating the String representation for: /content/assets-project/errors/404.html
org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource at '/content/assets-project/errors/404.html' not found: No resource found`

The same asset can be viewed to manage properties and also in the folder..
https://localhost:4502/assetdetails.html/content/dam/promo-tiles/indy500-v4-1135-1920x1920%20(1).jpg

[image]

We can also access the assets' json

[image]

what maybe the cause? And this happens only for few assets and not all.

Comment: just taking a stab here -> can you compare the permissions (ACLs) between the assets that are working and the ones that are not?

Comment: Since the error in the screenshot is ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, it could be an issue with just your browser, did you try out fixing this error in the first place. This article here should help you out -> https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/

Comment: Does this happens for assets in the same folder? You can access some of them but not others. ACL's could be a reason, though if you are using the default admin user that should not be an issue unless explicitly removed read permissions for specific assets.